# How to validate that json string has been passed correctly to php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

--This is different question that what has been asked before--

Sorry for such a noob question, but I'm really looking for a way to check if the json string has been passed correctly to php file or not. Basically, I would like to echo the json value and want to get feel of the data to process further. Since this is my first time working on php and java script, I seek your cooperation and help in overcoming this issue.

HTML code: where I'm displaying the fetched data:

```
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                            {
                                $fieldName[] = $row['fieldName'];
                                $fieldText[] = $row['fieldText'];
                                $fieldID[]   = $row['ID'];

                                if ($_GET['showname']){                                 
                                echo"<tr>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['fieldName']."</td>";
                                //echo '<td>'.'<input type = "text" class="form-control" disabled = "disabled" id ="fieldText['.$row["ID"].']"  name = "fieldText['.$row["ID"].']" value = "'.$row["fieldText"].'">'."</td>";

                                echo '<td>'.'<input type = "text" class="form-control" disabled = "disabled" id ="'.$row["ID"].'"  name = "fieldText['.$row["ID"].']" value = "'.$row["fieldText"].'">'."</td>";
                                //echo "<td>".$row['fieldText']."</td>";
                                echo "</tr>";}
```

JSON function: where I'm catching the value in the text boxes:

```
function updateVal() {
var node_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var c = 0;
var fieldName = [];
var fieldText = []
var ID = [];
for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) {
    var node = node_list[i];
    if (node.getAttribute('type') == 'text') {
        fieldName[c] = node.name;
        fieldText[c] = node.value;
        ID[c] = node.id;
        c++;
    }
}
var postData = {
    fieldName: fieldName,
    fieldText: fieldText,
    ID: ID
};

$.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "update.php",
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'

});}
```

Update.php FILE:

I'm having a hard time to see the json object and values associated with it. Do I need to put some div element on parent page and then return the values or so? please help, how to echo the json string.

```
$result = json_decode($myData,TRUE);

if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
echo "JSON is valid";
print_r($result);}
?>
```

Comment: What is the output of print_r($result); ?

Comment: no output. I'm not able to see anything on the page..